# Can't find Boost 1.34.1 signals lib

Tags: c++, boost, openscenegraph

I am trying to compile a `CIGI`'s MPV for `OpenSceneGraph` using `cmake`. It's not very recent, it requires boost `1.34.1.` So I downloaded it, `cmake` couldn't find the boost for a while. I put `set(Boost_DEBUG 1)` in the FindBoost.cmake and, amongst other things, got the following:

```
Searching for SIGNALS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_signals-vc100-mt-1_34_1;boost_signals-vc100-mt;boost_signals-mt-1_34_1;boost_signals-mt;boost_signals
Searching for SIGNALS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_signals-vc100-mt-gd-1_34_1;boost_signals-vc100-mt-gd;boost_signals-mt-gd-1_34_1;boost_signals-mt-gd;boost_signals-mt;boost_signals
Could not find the following Boost libraries:
    boost_signals
```

Now I am trying to find this library. [This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) instruction suggests I either build them myself or download them from a link, which is now broken. I couldn't built it with bjam (`bjam --toolset=msvc stage`) I kept getting error's like:
`libs\program_options\src\cmdline.cpp(198) : error C2668: 'boost::bind' : ambiguous call to overloaded function`
and
`unknown compiler version please run the configure tests and report the results`. Then I downloaded [this](http://ascend4.org/Binary_installer_for_Boost_on_MinGW) installer which had only dll of needed library, release I assume and I need debug as well. 
So a couple of questions presents itself:
1.Do I keep trying to compile boost, if so any tips?
2.Where do I get the libs I need?
3.I am assuming I need the .lib files not the .dll's, am i right?

I am really confused by now, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try running `bjam --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete`, if it completes successfully the libraries should be placed in `stage\lib`

Comment: @Praetorian still the same errors

Comment: Your problem could be the really old version of boost. I'm not sure what else you could try.

Comment: [Here's the list of the compilers](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_34_1.html) that Boost 1.34.1 supports. So, you should install MSVC8.0, i.e. VisualStudio 2005, and then build with `--toolset=msvc-8.0` option.

Comment: @IgorR. Actually, "supported". Boost 1.34.1 _supported_ MSVC8.0 at the time, but boost 1.34.1 has long since dropped into oblivion. I mean, `July 24th, 2007 12:00 GMT` is long ago.

Comment: @sehe well, 1.34.1 still supports it - just like it did when it was freshly released. But boost community doesn't support 1.34.1 anymore :).